# ARToolKit ARSimpleProj Error

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, artoolkit

When I open the ARSimpleProj in Android Studio and try to update the gradle version I get this message:

```
Failed to update the version of the Android Gradle plugin.
Please click 'OK' to perform a textual search and then update the build files manually.
```

After this, I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(58, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:
* The project 'ARSimpleProj' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Fix plugin version and sync project
* The project 'ARSimpleProj' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
* The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin.
```

I tried removing the `android->buildToolsVersion` and dependencies tag from the top-level, `build.gradle` file (as indicated in the `AS_Migration` document) but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally make it work. When opening the project on the Android Studio, I select "Remind me later" to the Android Gradle Plugin Update recommendation. After this, I could execute and install the application on my cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `JDK 1.7` in `Project Structure`. I had problems when using the `JDK 1.8` with ARToolkit for Android.